# Suppose $X, Y, Z$ are random variables, why is $E[E[g(X, Y, Z)|X]] = E[g(X, Y, Z)]?$

Tags: statistics, expected-value

Suppose $X$ is a continuous random variable, and $Y$ and $Z$ are discrete.

Why is the following true?

$$E\left[E\left[\left.\frac{I(Z=z)}{P(Z=z|X, Y)}P(Y=y|X)\right|X\right]\right]=E\left[\frac{I(Z=z)}{P(Z=z|X, Y)}P(Y=y|X)\right]$$

I know that I can factor out functions of $X$ from the inner expectation. However, I'm not sure why the inner expectation can be dropped?

Comment: What is your definition of $E[g(X,Y,Z)|X]$?

Comment: Conditional expectation of a function of $(X, Y, Z)$ given $X$.

Comment: I'm sorry if I gave the impression I didn't know the notation.  Which definition of the conditional expectation are you using?  The standard measure-theoretic one directly implies this equality as part of the definition.  See also, the law of total expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part of the usual definition of the conditional expectation $E[X|\mathcal{F}]$ of an integrable $X$ with respect to a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$, we have
$$A \in \mathcal{F} \implies E[E[X|\mathcal{F}]\mathbb{1}_A] = E[X\mathbb{1}_A]$$

Since every $\sigma$-algebra over the sample space $\Omega$ contains $\Omega$ itself, we set $A=\Omega$ above to find
$$E[E[X|\mathcal{F}]] = E[X].$$

Replace $X$ here with your $g(X,Y,Z)$ and replace $\mathcal{F}$ with $\sigma(X)$ to find your equality.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm most confused about the indicator involving $Z$ in my expression, i.e., it seems that $E[E[I(Z=z)|X]] = E[I(Z=z)]$. Why is this true?

Comment: @Adrian It's the same argument.  Replace $X$ with $I(Z=z)$ and replace $\mathcal{F}$ with $\sigma(X)$.